# Does Google hide search queries with HTTPS?

Tags: security, https, google-search

I commonly hear that since Google employs SSL for their search page, it hides your search queries. But the query is also kept in the URL eg.

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow
```

and since SSL does not have the capabilities for masking the URL, the query is visible to anyone sniffing the network.

Am I correct that the search queries on Google are not hidden due to SSL?

Comment: HTTP is "inside" of the SSL layer, so no, the URL isn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

No, URLs cannot be seen by network sniffers (as long as SSL is being used). They are first translated into IPs by the client then sent through the network, returning the result back to the client. You can see how it works [here](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/).